# Delete referenced rows in the same PostgreSQL table

Tags: database, postgresql

```
Example Table:

       GroupId, User, RefrenceToGroupId
Row 1: 102,     ABC,  null
Row 2: 103,     DEF,  102
Row 3: 104,     GHI,  102
Row 4: 105,     JKL,  103
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to delete the parent row, which would cascade and delete all the referenced members.

For example:

Let's say I delete Row 1:

```
Row 1: 102, ABC, null
```

What should happen since Row 2 and Row 3 have a reference to Row 1 they should get deleted, and Row 4 should also be deleted as it has a reference to row 2 which is being deleted.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on delete cascade` within the same table.

```
  foreign key(RefrenceToGroupId)
    references groups(GroupId)
    on delete cascade
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/h_fpoxCr).